# Site Hijacking RSS Feed and Entire Site in iFrame

Tags: wordpress, iframe, rss

The following site appears to be hijacking a client's content.

http://mothernova2.rssing.com/chan-24556607/latest.php

This is my client's site.

http://www.mothernova.com/

How would I go about blocking that domain from accessing the site?  It also appears they are pulling the site into an iframe allowing full browsing.

FYI, the site is using WordPress, WordFence and iThemes Security (if there are any settings I should add for blocking).

Comment: They're likely using your RSS fed - http://www.mothernova.com/feed/. You can make the feed contain only excerpts of posts, if you like. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-rss-feed-show-only-post-excerpts

Comment: Yes, we can do that but somehow they are displaying the entire site within their page (iframes I'm guessing).

Comment: You can set `X-Frame-Options` headers to prevent that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [framekilling script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), which uses javascript to check if your script is the top one.  Here's a simple version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top != self) top.location.replace(location);
</script>
```

One drawback to this approach: if there is a legitimate site iframing your code, you need to check the referrer and start adding exceptions.

And a question to answer before you do it: you're getting a pageview and ad impression from the annoying framing site; is there any reason why you need to go to the bother, when they're sending a few viewers to your client's content?

Comment: From what I can tell, they aren't sending visitors and they're hijacking Google rankings.  I'll try the framekilling script.

Comment: Well, I've added both the framekilling script and the <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"> to the site and neither appear to work.  Maybe RSSing is caching the site in some way.

Comment: When I go to the RSSing page, I'm seeing the link, but the content doesn't display in the frame (in both Chrome and Firefox).  Which unfortunately doesn't solve your problem.  But if the issue is hijacking Google rankings, breaking out of the frame isn't going to do it - the Google ranking comes from the words that have been sucked in to RSSing's page.

Answer (score 0):

The site owners of `rssing.com` are well known scrapers. And they are grabbing your content by RSS, hence the name `rssing.com`.

You can use the contact form to ask that they take your content down. Tell them they are clearly violating your TOS and copyright for your content.

[image]

*(I had to do this in the past for my own content scraped from my site; they did remove my site at my request.)*

Comment: My client is a lawyer in a past life and has lots of lawyer friends who have already stepped in and helped.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I wasn't implementing the above suggestions correctly (I was adding them at the page level), but they weren't working for me.  I did find this post and it seems to work as outlined.

http://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/rssing-com-good-or-bad/

I updated my .htaccess file with the suggested code.

Brett